redisearch vector search "ResponseError: Syntax error at offset 50 near DateTime"
I have a redisjson databse (with redisearch module) that contains a vector column and a timestamp column. I want query find the most similar items with a condition of time.
queries = [
    "Some text to search",

]
query = (
    Query('*=>[KNN 10 @vector $query_vector AS vector_score] @DateTime:[1696672140005 1696958220000]')
     .sort_by('vector_score')
     .return_fields('vector_score', 'title', 'DateTime')
    
     .dialect(2)
)
for i in range(len(queries)):
    encoded_query =  embedder.encode(queries[i])
    print(client.ft('idx:myindex').search(
        query,
        {
          'query_vector': np.array(encoded_query, dtype=np.float32).tobytes()
        }
    ).docs)

i want to find the most similar items but this error occurs
ResponseError: Syntax error at offset 50 near DateTime

You are attempting to execute hybrid search, but the numeric filter is in the wrong position. Filters must be added in place of "*".
An example from the docs:
FT.SEARCH movies "(@title:Dune @year:[2020 2022])=>[KNN 10 @movie_embedding $BLOB AS movie_distance]" PARAMS 2 BLOB "\x12\xa9\xf5\x6c" SORTBY movie_distance DIALECT 4

I recommend you run either Redis Stack or test Redis 8 M02. Redis 8 will deliver the query engine, JSON support and the rest of capabilities (time-series and probabilistic data structures)
